# What does ".//" represent while checking path?

Tags: mac, terminal

In Mac terminal, I see that for current directory we see files as `./` which represents files/folders in current directory.
but for the same sometimes we get `.//` , why is this needed? is there significance to this?
I checked that same file can be accessed using `./` or `.//` , then whats the use of
`.//`

Comment: the number of `/` is irrelevant, as you've seen, `./` is the same as `.//` ... and it's the same as `.////////` ... also `./folder/file` is `.////folder//file` etc etc ... as to why you "get" that, guess it depends on where you "get" that from

Comment: "`./` which represents files/folders in current directory" – Strictly `./` represents *the* current working directory, not files therein.

Comment: yes @Destroy666 , thanks for answering this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple slashes are ignored and merged into a single one, according to [Unix specification(s)](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_271):

> Multiple successive  characters are considered to be the same as one , except for the case of exactly two leading  characters

The leading `//` exception is optional and varies between implementation. Normally, it won't do anything special in popularly used systems, including macOS from question:

> If a pathname begins with two successive  characters, the first component following the leading  characters may be interpreted in an implementation-defined manner, although more than two leading  characters shall be treated as a single  character.

[Source](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_13)